# Organizing Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, organization

I'm making an android app and since I've just started I want to try get the most organised code/resources. In my strings.xml file so far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">GameController</string>
<string name="stop">Stop</string>
<string name="start">Start</string>
<string name="preferences">Preferences</string>
<string name="back">Back</string>
</resources>
```

All of the strings except app_name are used in an options menu. But since I will be adding much more strings I was thinking that it might be better to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">GameController</string>
<string name="menu_stop">Stop</string>
<string name="menu_start">Start</string>
<string name="menu_preferences">Preferences</string>
<string name="menu_back">Back</string>
</resources>
```

Is it the best way or should I use another system?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends on where the strings will be used. If "stop" will never be used anywhere but in a menu, calling it "menu_stop" is a good idea. If it'll be used all over the place then it should just be called "stop".

Also, XML comments are very useful for organizing resources.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GameController</string>

    <!-- Menu Strings -->
    <string name="menu_stop">Stop</string>
    <string name="menu_start">Start</string>
    <string name="menu_preferences">Preferences</string>
    <string name="menu_back">Back</string>
</resources>
```

Finally, if you find you have tons and tons of string resources you may want to go so far as to separate them into different xml files: menu_strings.xml, dialog_strings.xml, etc.

#### menu_strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Menu Strings -->
    <string name="menu_stop">Stop</string>
    <string name="menu_start">Start</string>
    <string name="menu_preferences">Preferences</string>
    <string name="menu_back">Back</string>
</resources>
```

#### dialog_strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="dialog_cancel_yes">Yes, cancel.</string>
    <string name="dialog_cancel_no">No, do not cancel.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Some of them will be used a few times, but if i had menu_stop and preferences_stop then I could change one without affecting the other.

Comment: these files must to be in the same `/values` folder? or I can add a new folder to organize these files? such as `/values/dialog_strings`

Comment: Android uses subfolders under /res to determine what device configuration each resource belongs to. I'm honestly not sure how it would react to deeper levels below that. It should be very easy to test with a HelloWorld app.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a subjective question, really. You should use whatever you find easier to handle. I certainly do the second type of naming when I'm using layouts and drawables (e.g. button_x, ninepatch_x, icon_x, etc.), just because it keeps them next to each other, and is easier to narrow down quickly with Content Assist. In XML, you can use comments to group them together, and add white space, just anything that makes it easier for you to find what you need, and quickly.