# how to find string name from string in android resourcesfile

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to create an application which can fetch the string name from the resource file in android when we search using string.Is there any way?
Suppose my strings.xml file has following

Hello world!

Now what i want to do is when i type Hello world in the search menu of my application it should return abc as the string name.

Comment: Did you mean [`Context.getString(int resId)`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)? What do you mean by *search using String*? Example?

Comment: If my xml resource file has following entry <string name="abc">hello world</string>.Is it possible to get res id name i.e. "abc" using hello world

Answer (score 1):

***1.*** When you say, "Suppose my strings.xml file has following", and there's a "Hello world!", it would mean your `strings.xml` would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

This means there are strings defined under Resources of your app which can be used by importing  `yourpackage.R` - that is how the compiler will identify values from `R`.

So what is the name of the string which has value "Hello world!" in your xml?

***2.*** To get that value, you would use:

```
getResources.getString(R.string.stringNameHere);
```

***3.*** And as per your requirement, i suggest you get all `strings` from your `strings.xml` in an array and run your search through that.

To know more about all that, please go through:

-> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

-> https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html

-> [Organizing Strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597216/organizing-strings-xml?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)` in your Activity. The string `yourstring` is defined in `Strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the defined strings by using reflection on R.string like this:

```
for (Field field : R.string.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
    try {
        Log.i("Strings", String.format("String %s = %s", field.getName(),
                                       getResources().getString(field.getInt(field))));
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```